# wordpress insert php parse error

Tags: php, wordpress, insert

It does not work because the second block does not know what $out is. I did not find how I can handle

```
[insert_php]
/* do something */
$out = smthing;
[/insert_php]

<html>
/*something */    

[insert_php]
echo $out;
[/insert_php]
</html>
```

**Edit:**
    How can I write a for loop, it did not work

```
[insert_php]foreach($elements as $element){ [/insert_php]
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="opt" value=[insert_php]echo $element; [/insert_php] > [insert_php] echo $element; [/insert_php]</input> </label>
[insert_php]}[/insert_php]
```

Comment: `#` means what follows is a comment. Use `$out = ...`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, problem is still continue. I think insert_php blocks are not related with each others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[insert_php]...[/insert_php]` shortcodes are totally separate from each other. The entire body of that tag must be complete and valid PHP code.

You can share the variable by using a global variable. I'd pick a name that's more unique than `$out`, to be on the safe side:

```
[insert_php]
global $MY_CUSTOM_TEMP_VAR;   
/* do something */
$MY_CUSTOM_TEMP_VAR = smthing;
[/insert_php]

<html>
/*something */    

[insert_php]
global $MY_CUSTOM_TEMP_VAR;  
echo $MY_CUSTOM_TEMP_VAR;
[/insert_php]
</html>
```

You can make a loop *inside* a *single* `[insert_php]...[/insert_php]` shortcode tag:

```
[insert_php]
foreach($elements as $element)
    echo "
       <label class='radio-inline'>
         <input type='radio' name='opt' value='" . esc_attr( $element ) ."'>$element</input>
       </label>
    ";
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: it writes $element in radio buttons